# UNPROCESSABLE ENTITY saving user on Ionic Platform Beta

Tags: ionic-framework

I have moved from Ionic Platform Alpha to Beta.

I have implemented signup and
login with success, but everytime I try to execute
save action I get this error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with
a status of 422 (UNPROCESSABLE ENTITY)
```

Just a snippet of my code:

```
user = Ionic.User.current();
console.log("User %s is authenticated: %s", user.id, user.isAuthenticated());
user.set('age', '25');
user.save();
```

This is the output:

```
User ee18171e-1384-4911-98ed-e1b2fc6e89bf is authenticated: true
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status
of 422 (UNPROCESSABLE ENTITY) (https://api.ionic.io/auth/user...
Ionic User: Object {response: XMLHttpRequest, error: Error}
```

Analyzing the error this is shown:

```
Field may not be null
```

But I can't figure which field is null is this request ....

Does someone know how to perform a save action on Ionic Platform Beta?

Answer (score 1):

Probably a little late for a reply here,
but just in case someone is looking for an answer.

When setting a user, Ionic is looking for an email address and password:

```
var details = {
'email': '$scope.data.email',
'password': $scope.data.password
}
Ionic.Auth.signup(details).then(
function(user){
user.migrate();
user.save(); // save the user to persist the migration changes
console.log('success');
},
function(user){
console(user + 'not added to ionic')
}
);
```

This will register the user